Validate record's constructor parameters values
I'm playing around with modern Java versions like 17 or 21 alongside Maven based project and I'm wondering is there any way to get constructor parameters values and simply print them or validate them and eventually throw an exception?
I'm posting the code I currently have:
An aggregate running validation:
public record User(
        Id id,
        Email email,
        Password password
) {
    public User {
        try (ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory()) {
            Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
            Map<String, String> validationErrorMessages = new HashMap<>();

            String idViolations = validator.validate(id).stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).toList().toString();
            if (!idViolations.equals("[]")) {
                validationErrorMessages.put(id.toString(), idViolations);
            }

            String emailViolations = validator.validate(id).stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).toList().toString();
            if (!emailViolations.equals("[]")) {
                validationErrorMessages.put(email.toString(), emailViolations);
            }

            String passwordViolations = validator.validate(id).stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).toList().toString();
            if (!passwordViolations.equals("[]")) {
                validationErrorMessages.put(password.toString(), passwordViolations);
            }

            if (!validationErrorMessages.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ValidationException(validationErrorMessages.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}

and Value Objects:
public record Id(@NotNull Long value) {}

@GroupSequence({Email.class, Additional.class})
public record Email(
        @NotNull
        @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$",
                groups = Additional.class,
                message = "Invalid e-mail format")
        String value
) {
}

@GroupSequence({Password.class, Additional.class})
public record Password(
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 12,
                message = "must be at least {min} characters long")
        @Pattern(regexp = ".*[a-z].*",
                groups = Additional.class,
                message = "must contain a small letter")
        @Pattern(regexp = ".*[A-Z].*",
                groups = Additional.class,
                message = "must contain a capital letter")
        @Pattern(regexp = ".*\\d.*",
                groups = Additional.class,
                message = "must contain a digit")
        @Pattern(regexp = ".*[#?!].*",
                groups = Additional.class,
                message = "must contain one of special characters: [#, ?, !]")
        String value
) {
}

What I want to achieve is to either annotate (with @Aggregate maybe?) the User record and have the validation done under the hood:
@Aggregate
public record User(
    Id id,
    Email email,
    Password password
) {}

Or even give up on annotation and have every single record stored inside a specific package validated without code duplication or annotations.
I've read something about annotation processors, byte buddy plugin or seen something about Java 21 constructor hooks, but the more I read the less I understand which solution fits my needs.

When you validate the parameters of the constructors of Id, Email, and Password at their construction time, there is no need to validate them again in the User constructor.

Good point. I wanted to have them validated in an aggregate and throw a single exception containing info on them all.

You may want to re-evaluate whether this branching logic (be it implicit or explicit) belongs here in the record constructor or somewhere else.  See Parse, Don't Validate: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/

Thank you so much for the lecture! I'm not into Although it was the first time I've seen some Haskell snippets, the reading gave me an idea to reconsider my code.

I would suggest using a builder pattern to build the object with validations in the builder method(s)

I'm lazy and I'm interested in a generic solution.

@RobertGardziński The Builder Pattern is a generic and effective solution for this type of problem. Design patterns are established to address specific challenges in software design, and they often provide a structured and efficient approach. It seems you're attempting to solve this problem in a more roundabout manner, but adopting a design pattern like Builder could streamline your implementation and improve maintainability
